# How do I work out what dependency I need for Spring Boot MultiValueMap in Gradle?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, dependencies

I have some code which needs access to `org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap`.

I am running IntelliJ IDEA on a Windows machine. I am getting a compilation error:

> "Cannot access org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap".

This error occurs on the following line of code (request is an object of type ClientHttpRequest), which is in a junit test file:

```
String authorization = request.getHeaders().getFirst("Authorization");
```

I have tried the following two import statements, based on the documentation for MultiValueMap (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html):

```
import org.springframework.util;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
```

However these do not work - latter parts of those statements are highlighted in red. I believe this is because I don't have the correct dependencies in build.gradle.

These are the Spring Framework dependencies I currently have:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core")
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT')
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT')
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT')
compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.8.RELEASE")
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile('org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-test')
```

Comment: 1. `org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap` 2. too broad to answer, if you do everything right it shouldn't happen, if it still happens try google 3. No, it should be `import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;`

Comment: Why don't you use the spring-boot dependency?

Comment: @Oleg: By dependency, I mean the dependencies section in my build.gradle file. Eg compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"). I have been googling this for the last half hour and I can't find anything that helps. You say "if you're doing everything right"... clearly I am NOT doing everything right, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I tried your suggestion (import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;) but that doesn't work either, and according to the documentation for MultiValueMap (link in my post) I think org.springframework.util should be sufficient.

Comment: @Christian: I'm not sure what you mean. I already have several springframework dependencies, but they do not seem to be sufficient. I will update my post to add more info.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a fix!

The answer was on this page here: https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/23/better-dependency-management-for-gradle

It appears that using gradle for dependency management for Spring-Boot can be problematic because you need so many lines in your dependencies section, like the ones I listed above.

I followed the instructions on that page, inserting the following lines into my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.1.1.RELEASE'
    }
}
```

My code now compiles. I still don't know where I would have been able to find the correct individual dependency for build.gradle, but using this plugin it is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You *may* be doing a bit too much work here.  Alternatively, you run the risk of having your dependencies slightly out-of-sync.

The only dependency you need is `spring-boot-starter`, which has a transitive dependency to the correct `spring-core` version you want.

You can use this in your build.gradle file:

```
compile'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.5.10.RELEASE'
```

If you want to use the Gradle plugin for Spring Boot (which [can be found here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html)), place the version of Spring Boot you want into the plugin section and omit the versions on your dependencies.

Comment: If you use the Spring Boot plugin for Gradle, it will override the versions of dependencies it cares about.

Answer (score -1):

This line would go at the top of your class

```
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
```

And while I'm not necessarily familiar with this exact library, looking on [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core/5.0.3.RELEASE) tells me that you would need something like this in your `build.gradle` file

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral() 
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.0.3.RELEASE'
}
```

Comment: Hi, the syntax you suggest for the dependencies section in my build.gradle does not appear to be correct. It will not compile. My other dependencies look like this: compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"). Please could you give me more information on how to browse mvnrepository to find the correct dependency? I have tried searching it for MultiValueMap, but I get no results.

Comment: Hmm, this is the syntax I'm used to myself. I actually just copied this straight from the link I put in the answer. So, sorry, can't help you there. I usually just Google "maven repository com.name.of.the.thing" and don't really have issues with it. Did you re-build the project with ```clean build``` tasks

Comment: I think the syntax you'd be looking for would be ```compile('org.springframework:spring-core:5.0.3-RELEASE')```. The way you're used to looks like its in the format ```compile('group:name:version')``` so I'd try that

Comment: I can add a separate dependencies section using the syntax you suggest, and that has no syntax errors... but does not fix my original problem. However, I found a plugin that fixes it (see my Answer above). Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: Gradle has flexible support for declaring dependencies and j.seashell's syntax is also correct. In fact, the syntax used in the original question is not idiomatic, as the parentheses are usually omitted and use single quotes (') instead of double quotes (") since the double quotes are only needed if you are doing string interpolation.